# ¿Llamar diferente version de Python en el terminal Windows?

Tags: python, windows10

Desearía poder llamar a cualquier versión de Python que haya instalado sobre el terminal de Windows (tengo 2.7, 3.6 y 3.7). Me gustaría llamarle con `python`,`python36` y `python37` o de cualquier otra forma si tiene ideas más relevantes. Sin embargo, cuando intenté hacerlo para Python 3.7, no pareció funcionar.

```
C:\>set PATH=C:\Program Files\Python 3.7;%PATH%

C:\>set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib

C:\>python
Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Aquí están mi variables de entorno :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Windows suele estar instalado el [lanzador `py.exe`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) que puede detectar las versiones que tienes instaladas y permitirte elegir cuál usar.

Para ver si lo tienes correctamente configurado prueba (en una terminal):

```html
> py --list
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.7-32 *
 -3.6-64
```

(Esto es lo que me sale a mi)

Cuando pones `py` sin parámetros te lanza la versión más reciente, pero si quieres otra puedes especificarla tras un guión. Por ejemplo:

```html
> py
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:05:16) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()

> py -3.6
Python 3.6.0 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit
```

También puedes usarlo para lanzar scripts, naturalmente:

```html
> py -3.6 holamundo.py
Hola!
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es de la terminal de windows

```
py -3.11
Unable to create process using 
'C:\Users\asd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe': El sistema no 
puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
```

Terminal en vsc

```
PS C:\Workspace\hola python> c:
PS C:\Workspace\hola python> cd "c:/Workspace/hola python"
PS C:\Workspace\hola python> & c:/Python311/python.exe "c:/Workspace/hola 
python/example.py" 
Hello world
PS C:\Workspace\hola python> python
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit 
(AMD64)] on win32
```

A mi me aparece eso. El tema es que cuando corro el programa con el botón de play desde el editor, utiliza un path que tiene el interprete de python 3.11.Pero cuando estoy en la terminal y tipeo python usa la versión 3.8 , que tengo instalada de antes. Quisiera usar la versión 3.11 en la terminal pero no se como configurar eso y que coincidan.