# ¿Cómo colocar una versión específica de Python en el comando python en cmd?

Tags: python, windows, windows10

Tengo python3.6 en una carpeta y me gustaria ser capaz de llamarlo con `python3` o `python3.6` o una cosa equivalente.

```
C:\Users\...\ChatbotRASA_Room-reservation>C:\Python36\python
Python 3.6.7 (v3.6.7:6ec5cf24b7, Oct 20 2018, 13:35:33) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer este alias? Me gustaria ser capaz de llamarlo con:

```
>>> python3 cosa.py
```

Comment: Hola, ¿has intentado usar `pyenv`? No se si es lo que buscas. Puedes encontrar información en [Github-pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

Comment: Aunque veo que usas Windows, no se si esté implementado para Windows.

Comment: Mira a ver si te vale esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/222191/7123

Answer (score 0):

deber ir a la ruta de instalacion y cambiar los nombres de lo `python.exe` por `python3` y ya que la ruta esta definida en el path windows solo buscara ese nombre dentro de las carpetas del path si quieres cambiar tambien el pip es igual!
por defecto la ruta de python3 es:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\+version python
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\+version python\Scripts\ # ruta del pip
```